# $k[X_1,\ldots X_n]/(X_1)\cong k[X_2,\ldots, X_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove that $k[X_1,\ldots X_n]/(X_1)\cong k[X_2,\ldots, X_n]$, in order to do so, I'm trying to find an epimorphism such that $(X_1)$ is kernel, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why do not just make $\phi$ reducing mod $X_1$? It preserves $k[X_2,\ldots,X_{n}]$ and vanishes on $X_1\cdot W(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \in (X_1)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$\phi$ reducing mod $X_1$"? can you be more explicit?

Comment: For $W(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \in k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ let $\phi(W) = W(0,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$.

Comment: Why $\ker \phi = (X_1)$?

Comment: This is very clear once you think about it some time. Please don't let us do *all* your work. After all, you want to learn something?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg It's just a revision of this subject, anyway I'm trying to prove this right now.

Comment: @Baranovskiy I think I understood what do you mean, it's the generalization of this theorem: If $f\in k[t]$ such that $f(0)=0$, then $t|f$, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, to make a ring homomorphism $\varphi:k[X_1,\dots,X_n]\to R$ out of a polynomial ring (here $R$ is an arbitrary **commutative** (thanks Cihan!) ring), it is enough to make a ring homomorphism $\phi:k\to R$ from the coefficient ring and then extend it to a homomorphism of the whole polynomial ring by deciding what $\varphi$ should do on the indeterminates, that is, by choosing $\varphi(X_1),\dots,\varphi(X_n)$. For example, I can make a map $\varphi: \mathbb Z[x,y]\to\mathbb Q$ by starting with the inclusion $\phi:\mathbb Z\hookrightarrow\mathbb Q$ given by $n\mapsto n$ and defining $\varphi(n)=\phi(n)$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$, $\varphi(x)=4/5$, and $\varphi(y)=-17/9$. The choice of $\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(y)$ is completely arbitrary in the sense that any choice gives a genuine ring homomorphism.

For your particular problem, you need to choose a map $k\to k[X_2,\dots,X_n]$ and extend it to the indeterminates in such a way that the resulting map is surjective and the kernel is $(X_1)$, as you said. What is a natural way of doing this?

Comment: very interesting answer! I've never thought in this way

Comment: $R$ should be commutative for this to work in general. $X_i$'s commute with each other in the polynomial ring, hence so will their images.